# Error 1071 en laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Cuando realizo la migración error 1071, campo demasiado largo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Para quien lee esta pregunta rápidamente, puede no quedar claro el problema concreto y que estás compartiendo la solución. Quizás sería recomendable aclarar esa parte.

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel 5,4 migración: especificado clave fue la solución de error demasiado largo**

Laravel 5.4 utiliza el utf8mb4 conjunto de caracteres por defecto, que incluye soporte para almacenar “emoji” en la base de datos. Si está actualizando su aplicación desde laravel 5.3, usted no está obligado a cambiar a este conjunto de caracteres.
Y, de acuerdo con su documentación el problema es que estoy corriendo versión de MySQL anterior a 5.7.7 o MariaDB antes 10.2.2 (mi caso). En caso de que usted está ejecutando versiones de MySQL o MariaDB mayor que éstos lo más probable es que usted no tendrá este problema en absoluto.

En caso de que usted tiene este problema - aquí son las posibles soluciones:

**1. Actualice MariaDB / MySQL**

Para actualizar MariaDB en Mac usando Brew , primero que hay que desvincular la actual usando:

brew unlink mariadb
y luego instalar una dev desde

brew install mariadb --devel
Eso va a instalar MariaDB versión 10.2.3 que funciona bien. Recuerde que después de la instalación se hace lo necesario para detener / iniciar el servicio:

brew services stop mariadb
brew services start mariadb

**2. Seguir con UTF-8**

En caso de que no desea utilizar el utf8mb4 (que ahora es la configuración por defecto en laravel 5.4) - por el contrario desea seguir con UTF-8 que estaba en uso en laravel 5.3 y todas las versiones anteriores, sólo tiene que editar /config/database.php y encontrar estas dos líneas en el controlador de MySQL:

'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
y reemplazarlos con la

'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
Eso va a dejar de usar el utf8mb4 y cambiará de nuevo a UTF-8. Lo bueno de esto es que usted será capaz de encajar un 25% más caracteres en las mismas columnas en la base de datos en comparación con utf8mb4 y que usted será capaz de utilizar las bases de datos y proyectos existentes sin necesidad de convertirlos si no' t desea. Y el inconveniente es que algunos caracteres no podrán ser guardados en la base de datos como éste mac carácter de comando o ⌘ algunos emojis. Utf8 puede única tienda  Plano Unicode  mientras utf8mb4 puede almacenar cualquier carácter Unicode. Utf8mb4 también es 100% compatible con UTF-8.

**3. Uso utf8mb4 sin actualización de MySQL / MariaDB**

En caso de que quiera utilizar utf8mb4 pero no quiere o simplemente no pueden actualizar su MySQL / MariaDB existe una solución simple propuesto por la documentación laravel. Todo lo que necesita hacer es editar AppServiceProvider situada en App \ Providers \ AppServiceProvider.php y añadir la siguiente línea en el método de arranque () y la carga de la fachada de esquema:

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
Lo que va a hacer es realmente cambiar la longitud máxima de campo predeterminada en la base de datos y, de hecho acortar su longitud máxima de cadena de 255 a máximo de 191 caracteres (UTF-8 utiliza 3 bytes por carácter, mientras que utf8mb4 utiliza 4 bytes por carácter su campo ahora puede contener 25% menos caracteres 255 * 75% = 191,25). Así que si no se establece el campo de cadena con la mano en la migración al nuevo defecto será 191. Puede aumentar la longitud si lo necesita de forma manual al definirlo:

$table->string('name', 255);
Pero esto no será posible en campos indexados ya que estos no pueden tener más de 191 caracteres. Así que tenga esto en cuenta en caso de que tiene pensado usar utf8mb4.

En caso de que quiera convertir la base de datos de UTF8 a utf8mb4  para los proyectos existentes o si está actualizando desde Larvel 5.3 o mayor a 5.3 laravel El código tiene que ejecutar para cada base de datos, tabla y la columna:

Asegúrate de que tienes las copias de seguridad de bases de datos antes de hacer estos cambios !!!!

## For each database:

ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

## For each table:

ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

## For each column:

ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

## (Don’t just blindly copy-paste this! The exact statement depends on the column type, maximum length, and other properties. The above line is just an example for a `VARCHAR` column.)

Una vez más: cuando se convierte de UTF-8 a utf8mb4, la longitud máxima de una columna de clave o índice no ha cambiado en términos de bytes, pero desde utf8mb4 utiliza un 25% más bytes por carácter sus columnas ahora puede aceptar menos caracteres. Por lo tanto, es más pequeño en términos de caracteres, debido a que la longitud máxima de un personaje es ahora cuatro bytes en lugar de tres.

Por ejemplo, una columna TINYTEXT puede contener hasta 255 bytes, que se correlaciona a 85 tres bytes o 63 caracteres de cuatro bytes. Digamos que tiene una columna TINYTEXT que utiliza UTF-8, sino que debe ser capaz de contener más de 63 caracteres. Teniendo en cuenta este requisito, no se puede convertir esta columna para utf8mb4 menos que cambie también el tipo de datos a un tipo ya como TEXTO - porque si se iba a tratar de llenarlo con caracteres de cuatro bytes, sólo sería capaz de introducir 63 caracteres, pero no más.

Lo mismo ocurre con las claves de índice. El motor de almacenamiento InnoDB tiene una longitud máxima de 767 bytes de índice, por lo que para las columnas UTF8 o utf8mb4, se puede indexar un máximo de 255 caracteres o 191, respectivamente. Si actualmente tiene columnas utf8 con índices superiores a 191 caracteres, se deberá indexar un menor número de caracteres cuando se utiliza utf8mb4.

Si usted planea usar utf8mb4 asegúrese de configurar el servidor MySQL en consecuencia editando el archivo /etc/my.cnf en consecuencia:

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

**Conclusión**

Si su aplicación no utilizará ningún carácter o emojis o idiomas como el chino, japonés y coreano especiales que está más probablemente bien se pegue con UTF-8. Pero si se puede - usted debe mover a utf7mb4 ya que le impedirá perder caracteres de 4 bytes cuando un usuario anuncios éstos en los comentarios o en mensaje o cada vez que se almacenan estos en su base de datos. Siempre debe esforzarse para soporte completo de Unicode en todas partes de sus aplicaciones y la actualización de su base de datos y el código podría tomar algún tiempo, pero es sin duda vale la pena el tiempo y esfuerzo.